# Microsoft Graph API - Creating a custom dashboard

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am a big user of Delve and understand vaguely how it works - but I wondered today if anyone has been creating custom dashboards with a different perspective using the API's available?

Microsoft claim that- The Microsoft Graph gives you:

- A unified API endpoint for accessing aggregated data from multiple Microsoft cloud services in a single response
- Seamless navigation between entities and the relationships among them
- Access to intelligence and insights coming from the Microsoft cloud

So with this in mind and when I look at the API's available they are very much about 'Me' (i.e. my manager, people related to me.. etc)

I wonder however, would be possible to develop a dashboard to take a different perspective perhaps and view information related to another object such as a 'Project' for instance (with a unique id). The goal would be to view all the information, relationships and connections that tie back to a particular project, rather than a person.

So my question is.. is this possible, does it make sense to do this and has anyone seen it used in this way to surface information?

Answer (score 0):

I think "me" is a stand-in ID that can often be replaced with the real ID of groups, users and other resources.  Think of it as way of cutting down calls just to find out stuff about a users that has delegated access rights to an app using the Graph API.  You can use the graph API to look up more general IDs (hint: the $filter on the end of the API URL is quite handy in restricting what resources are returned when listing things such as groups).

Answer (score 0):

you are right, today Microsoft Graph API exposes data for Office 365 and other Microsoft cloud services that have a gravitational center around users and people centric scenarios. In particular the calculated insights that are exposed (trendingAround and workingWith) are for the user only. However, data around groups is also exposed via the API and you can build dashboards that expose information around groups. Furthermore with the introduction of the Planner service and their support for tasks you can also build experiences that track tasks and plans for a given user or group (please take into account that the Planner service is only available today for North American customers on First Release program, we will be expanding the footprint in the months to come).